# Copy a child record from a parent record's related list to another parent record's related list

Tags: visual-workflow, related-list, record, childrecords

I am looking to copy a child record from a parent record's related list to another parent record's related list. I am looking to automate this process. I am thinking of using a flow such as autolaunched or record-triggered flow to do this? Is this possible?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean cloning a record and linking it to a different parent?  Yes you can do that with autoluanch or record-triggered flow, depending on your use case.